# Find a closed formula for the generating function given the recursion equation.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, recursion

Suppose we have the recursion equation $b_{n+2}=5b_{n+1}-2b_n$. where $b_0=1, b_1 = 2$. I'm trying to find a closed formula for the generating function. I tried to find the characteristic equation and obtained $r^2-5r+2=0$. Then we could find $b_n = Ar_1^n+Br_2^n$ by solving $A$ and $B$ from $b_0$ and $b_1$. The final result is
$$
b_n = \frac{\sqrt{17}-1}{2\sqrt{17}}\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)^n+\frac{\sqrt{17}+1}{2\sqrt{17}}\left(\frac{5-\sqrt{17}}{2}\right)^n
$$
I wonder is there a different approach to solve for the generating function using recursive equation?

Comment: Let $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n$ be the OGF. Multiply both sides of your equation by $x^{n+2}$ and sum over $n$ (start from $n = 0$), you get
$$f(x) - b_0 - b_1x = 5x(f(x) - b_0) - 2x^2f(x) \implies \cdots$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course. The generating function has the form$$f(r)=\frac{Ar+B}{r^2-5r+2}=\frac{C}{r-r_1}+\frac{D}{r-r_2},$$
but $A,B$ are not your constants. You can expand it by the geometric series and hopefully you get the same result.